# Lazy Loading in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have used Primefaces `DataTable` and `Datascroller`with version 5.3.x. I have a requirement which should have multiple rows . the exising one is like fetching all the records(more than 100 records) at the same time. I have a idea of lazy loading with a component that supports global filter and lazy loading with collapse panel(should close the previous opened row when new row is selected) inside each row. Can someone please guide me on this , there is a ongoing issue on performance when it fetches all the records at the stretch

Comment: Searchh the PF documemtation with ctrl-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have existing solution on [Lazy datatable](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml). Your service should extend `LazyDataModel` and implement methods on how to fetch data. Combine that with filter and you are good to go.

Comment: i have already worked on lazy datatable extending lazydatamodel. Just on having a better learning curve and wanted to know other components that supports lazy loading other than datatable and datascroller